# Static routes in ISC DHCP

Tags: dns, routing, dhcp

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server at home running bind and ISC DHCP.  Bind is caching from unblock-us.com so that I can get access to US Netflix content.  This all works fine.

I'm running into trouble when using the Android Netflix app.  Apparently, the app has Google's DNS servers hard coded, so it ignores what is provided by DHCP. I've added a filter in my router to block WAN access on port 53 for all but my server's IP.  This isn't helping because when Google DNS isn't accessible, the app just hangs instead of falling back to the DNS assigned by DHCP.

I think I can set up static routes in my DHCP configuration so that Google's DNS 8.8.8.8 routes to my DNS server at 192.168.0.102, but I have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be great.